# How to know the probability distribution without knowing the probability density?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

I have an example in my textbook with the following:

*Let $\pi$ be the target distribution with a strictly positive continuous density $g$ on $A$, that is*

$\pi(A)=\int\limits_{A}g(x)dx$

...then later on the book explains that we are trying to approximate the Boltzman distribution (which would be $\pi$ in this case), using the hit and run, which is an algorithm that requires knowing $g(x)$, the pdf.

I'm wondering how is it possible to know $g(x)$ without knowing $\pi(A)$?

The best answer I can come up with is that it is possible to have a constant added to $g(x)$, like in differential equations, which might prevent us from knowing its exact form.  But is that the only reason?

**EDIT**: I'll admit this question is vague, but maybe what I'm trying to get at is - how do we approximate a distribution without sampling from that distribution?  (for some distributions that are difficult to sample, such as Boltzmann?)

**EDIT AGAIN AFTER SETTING BOUNTY**:  There is a common example for this type of sampling which I will use here to illustrate my confusion:  Say there is a circle inside of a square, and we wish to know the probability of randomly throwing a pebble and landing inside of the circle (obviously the answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$).  I understand that we can use a sampling method like MCMC (Markov Chain Monte Carlo) to do this.  But, in this case the sampling will tell us the outcome, with a 1 being inside the circle, and a 0 being outside the circle.  On a continuous distribution this is analogous to knowing *a priori* the pdf on the 2-d surface.  In which case we already know the pdf of the distribution which we are trying to approximate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of representing $\pi(A)=\int_A g(x)dx$, which specified that $g(x)$ already exists, assume for a second that you just had a function $\pi:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow [0,1]$ with $\mathcal{A}$ the collection of all subsets of the support.

Working in the univariate domain, $\pi(A)$ is the mass assigned to $A$, and could be represented using the CDF: $G(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x g(x)dx$. In this situation $g(x) = \frac{d}{dx} G(x)$.

The important thing here is to note that $\pi$ can be well defined, and $G(x)$ can be well defined, without $g(x)$ being defined at all. $\pi(A)$ is just a function mapping from $\mathcal{A}$ to the set $[0,1]$, and $G(x)$ is just equal to $\pi([-\infty,x])$.

So because the derivative does not always exist, $G(x)$ and $\pi(A)$ can exist without $g(x)$ being well defined.

Comment: Your answer is getting me closer, thanks @RyanWarnick.  But I still do not understand how “$\pi$ can be well-defined, and $G(x)$ can be well-defined, without $g(x)$ being defined at all”?  I am struggling to come up with a concrete example.  If $\pi(A)$ is to return a value between 0 and 1, then are you saying it can do so without evaluating the integral, and via some other means?  It would help me if you gave a concrete example.  Specifically I am interested in how to approximate a Boltzmann distribution, without being able to sample from a Boltzmann distribution?

Comment: Thinking of $\pi$ as a function mapping sets to $[0,1]$, all it has to do is have the properties of probability distributions (whole space is assigned to 1, null set assigned to 0, etc.) to be a probability distribution. When you do $\int_A g(x) dx$ you are just coming up with another way of representing a map from $\mathcal{A}$ to $[0,1]$. You could just define a function on the collection of sets instead.

Comment: If you have the math background, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)), [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure), and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem)

Comment: Right, so if I have that mapping from $A-> [0,1]$ then why do I even care what the analytical pdf is anymore?  all that really matters is that i get the probability associated with each point on the domain.

Comment: I read the links that you sent me.  It seems to me like something like the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm could be used to approximate the mapping $A -> [0,1]$, right?  thanks @RyanWarnick